# DataGridView only shows column names, no data on rows

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, odp.net

Please help, I'm tryng to make a program that will let the user get data from an Oracle database to a datagridview and let them export to Excel, but when getting the data, the DGV only shows a the column names and a single blank row. I'm getting the data from an Oracle View and I know that the tables have data.
Here is my code (I've cleared the connection data for security).

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client 'ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Types
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Threading

Public Class frmReport2
Dim rs As New Resizer
Dim UpdateThread As Thread
Dim UpdateThreadStart As New ThreadStart(AddressOf QueryDataBase)
Dim CallDataBindToDataGrid As New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Me.DataBindToDataGrid)
Dim MyDataSet As DataSet
Dim MyDataAdapter As OracleDataAdapter
Dim MyConnection As New OracleConnection("")
Private Sub frmReport2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    rs.FindAllControls(Me)
    TStripStLabel.Text = "Listo"


End Sub

Private Sub frmReport2_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    rs.ResizeAllControls(Me)
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBuscar.Click
    UpdateThread = New Thread(UpdateThreadStart)
    UpdateThread.IsBackground = True
    UpdateThread.Name = "Update Thread"
    UpdateThread.Start()


End Sub

' Sub routine that is to be executed on Form's thread.
Public Sub DataBindToDataGrid()
    DGVOra.DataSource = MyDataSet
    DGVOra.DataMember = "AUX_STATUS"
    MyDataAdapter = Nothing
    MyDataSet = Nothing
End Sub

' Sub routine used by the background thread to query database.
Public Sub QueryDataBase()
    MyDataSet = New DataSet()
    MyConnection.Open()
    Dim MyQueryString As String = "SELECT * FROM AUX_STATUS WHERE FECHA_INICIO " &
        "BETWEEN '" + DateFchInicio.Value + "' AND '" + DateFchFin.Value + "' AND HORA_INICIO BETWEEN '" + DateHrInicio.Value + "' AND '" + DateHrFin.Value + "'"
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(MyQueryString, MyConnection)
    MyDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
    'LblStatus.Text = "Buscando Información"
    TStripStLabel.Text = "Buscando Información"
    MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet, "AUX_STATUS")
    MyConnection.Close()
    'LblStatus.Text = "Operación finalizada"
    TStripStLabel.Text = "Operación Finalizada"
    ' Make asynchronous function call to Form's thread.
    Me.BeginInvoke(CallDataBindToDataGrid)
End Sub

Private Sub SalirToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SalirToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Estas seguro que deseas salir?", "Desea Salir?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
    'MsgBox("Estas seguro que deseas salir?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Desea Salir?", Msg) = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I stopped reading after this line: `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`.  **NEVER-EVER** use that statement.  It exists for a very special usage case that new code should never encounter.

Comment: @TnTinMn I've removed the line but stil gets me the error described above

Comment: I've checked with another table and it does get me data to the DGV

Comment: Based on your last comment, what happens if you just run the query you are using? Is it possible that it returns no data?

Comment: @Fabulous I've checked the query on SQL Developer and it does get me data, but on the DGV it only shows the column names and a blank row

Comment: I'm looking at the code for potential causes now, did you run the query generated by the code? Which brings me to another issue, try to use parameters as opposed to concatenating strings because that [opens you up](https://www.xkcd.com/327/) to [sql injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @Fabulous Yes I have run the query on SQL developer and it does return data

Comment: Verify the result of `MyQueryString`.  The code is using implicit conversion of presumably a DateTimePicker.Value that has a time component.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks!!  I verified the result and made the appropiate changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I needed only the Date and for each of my DateTimePicker, I added this to each of the values on `MyQueryString`:

```
DateFchInicio.Value.ToShortDateString
DateFchFin.Value.ToShortDateString
DateHrInicio.Value.ToLongTimeString
DateHrFin.Value.ToLongTimeString
```